# How to clear page cache when hitting back button on browser (IE,Chrome,Firefox Safari)?

Tags: model-view-controller

How to clear the cache of browser when hitting the back button on browser (IE,Chrome,Firefox Safari) In MVC4.tried with the following code but its not working 
                                             [How to refresh page when hitting back button on browser (IE,Chrome,Firefox Safari)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833452/how-to-refresh-page-when-hitting-back-button-on-browser-ie-chrome-firefox-safar)

Can you guys help me out to do this.

Thanks,
Subhnai.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell browser to discard old page and fetch latest from server by specifying it in `HTML > Head`

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate" />
```